# put operations CRUD on a single file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**Hello
I am developing an application with ASP.NET API, i created the controller entity and the MVC controllers that my generated CRUD operations in the view as follows (see picture), each operation in a file how to put it all in a single file.

**
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVowj.png)
controller code:

```
    // GET: /Clients/
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.CLIENT.ToList());
}

// GET: /Clients/Details/5
public ActionResult Details(long? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Client_H Client_H = db.Client_H.Find(id);
    if (Client_H == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(Client_H);
}

// GET: /Clients/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

// POST: /Clients/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="ID,nom,prenom,CODE,ADRESSE,BQE_VILLE,ADRESSE,TEL")] Client_H Client_H)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Client_H.Add(Client_H);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(Client_H);
}

// GET: /Clients/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(long? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Client_H Client_H = db.Client_H.Find(id);
    if (Client_H == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(Client_H);
}

// POST: /Clients/Edit/5
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="ID,nom,prenom,CODE,ADRESSE,BQE_VILLE,ADRESSE,TEL")] Client_H Client_H)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(Client_H).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(Client_H);
}

// GET: /Clients/Delete/5
public ActionResult Delete(long? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Client_H Client_H = db.Client_H.Find(id);
    if (Client_H == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(Client_H);
}

// POST: /Clients/Delete/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(long id)
{
    Client_H Client_H = db.Client_H.Find(id);
    db.Client_H.Remove(Client_H);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

}

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Do you want one .cshtml file for all CRUD operations? Why? That sounds like an XY problem. Aren't you simply looking for editor templates and display templates?

Comment: how to put CRUD operations in one file?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand well what do you mean by "how to put it all in a single file"?

If you want to have all CRUD function in on 1 view, you can use jquery POST & GET.

- https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
- https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/